# Creating a data.frame with combinations of strings in R

Tags: string, r, text, combinations

Suppose I have a one-column data.frame with strings such as:

```
> df<-data.frame(str=c("string1","string2","string3"))
> df
      str
1 string1
2 string2
3 string3
```

What is the most efficient way to create a two-column data.frame that contains every combination of the strings in 'df' (including self-combos) in sequential columns, like this:

```
> df2
     strA    strB
1 string1 string1
2 string2 string2
3 string3 string3
4 string1 string2
5 string1 string3
6 string2 string1
7 string2 string3
8 string3 string1
9 string3 string2
```

My actual data.frames contain ~1500-4500 strings.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two possible solutions:

```
df <- data.frame(str=c("string1","string2","string3"),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


do.call(rbind, strsplit(outer(df[, 1], df[, 1], paste), " "))

expand.grid(df[, 1], df[, 1])
```

Not sure how efficient or fast they are.

The new GitHub tidyr package's `separate` function may be of use here: https://github.com/hadley/tidyr/blob/master/R/separate.R